# How to Prevent conflict of data by MySQL UNION

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch multiple table data with MySQL UNION to high-chart with the following code. It gives wrong graph on some dates, By removing or changing that date it fixes the problem.

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");

$db->beginTransaction();
try{    
    $query = "SELECT dr.dates, COUNT(a.marks) AS t1marks, COUNT(b.marks) AS t2marks, COUNT(c.marks) AS t3marks  FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(date_column)) AS dates FROM `table1`
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(date_column)) FROM `table2`
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(date_column)) FROM `table3`) AS dr 
    LEFT JOIN table1 AS a ON dr.dates = DATE(a.date_column) 
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON dr.dates = DATE(b.date_column)
    LEFT JOIN table3 AS c ON dr.dates = DATE(c.date_column)
    GROUP BY dr.dates ORDER BY dates ASC";
    $done= $db->prepare($query);
    $done->execute();
    $rows = $done->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $dates = $t1marks = $t2marks = $t3marks = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $dates[] = $row['dates'];
        $t1marks[] = $row['t1marks'] == null ? 0 : (int) $row['t1marks'];
        $t2marks[] = $row['t2marks'] == null ? 0 : (int) $row['t2marks'];
        $t3marks[] = $row['t3marks'] == null ? 0 : (int) $row['t3marks'];
    }

    $output = json_encode( array( array( 'data' => $t1marks, 'name'  => 'class 1'),
        array( 'data' => $t2marks, 'name'  => 'class 2'),
        array( 'data' => $t3marks, 'name'  => 'class 3')
     ) );   

    $db->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
   echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9WZJwBunnEHjy6MMQGYSbt/5)

with `var_export($row);`

`array ( 'dates' => '2019-08-12', 'class1' => '8', 'class2' => '8', 'class3' => '8' )`

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: Let's see input data and output _data_ (not graph).  And point out one of them that is incorrect.

Comment: @RickJames please have a look at this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9WZJwBunnEHjy6MMQGYSbt/4), output of the data?

Comment: FYI, it doesn't make sense to `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` if you are going to iterate the array.  You should instead use individual fetch calls in a loop.  What transaction ate you `commit`ting? The SELECT query?  Also, `$dates = $t1marks = $t2marks = $t3marks = array();` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I will include that advice in my answer if you can make the necessary improvements to your question.  Do a `var_export($rows);` then show me what isn't quite right.

Comment: Keep the code block.  Include the dbfiddle.  Remove all of the images, they aren't helpful.  Show the var_export of $rows.  Show what $rows _should_ be.

Comment: Define "wrong" in the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic situation of `JOIN`s creating multiple rows for the same data and messing up aggregated values. To avoid this problem, do your aggregation in subqueries for each table:

```
SELECT d.date,
       COALESCE(t1.marks, 0) AS class1,
       COALESCE(t2.marks, 0) AS class2, 
       COALESCE(t3.marks, 0) AS class3
FROM (SELECT DATE(date_column) AS date FROM `table1`
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(date_column) FROM `table2`
      UNION
      SELECT DATE(date_column) FROM `table3`) AS d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(date_column) AS date,
                  COUNT(marks) AS marks
           FROM table1
           GROUP BY date) t1 ON t1.date = d.date
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(date_column) AS date,
                  COUNT(marks) AS marks
           FROM table2
           GROUP BY date) t2 ON t2.date = d.date
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(date_column) AS date,
                  COUNT(marks) AS marks
           FROM table3
           GROUP BY date) t3 ON t3.date = d.date
ORDER BY d.date
```

Output:

```
date        class1  class2  class3
2019-08-12  2       2       2
2019-08-13  0       1       2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9WZJwBunnEHjy6MMQGYSbt/6)

Note that with `UNION` without `ALL`, you don't need to bother with `SELECT DISTINCT` as any duplicates will be removed by the `UNION`. Also note we use `COALESCE` to avoid displaying `NULL` values when a class has no marks for a given date.

Comment: @Peace ...next step, fixing the db structure that demands such a complicated, hard-to-read, and inefficient query.

Comment: it might be fecal-polish in this situation, but `USING` can used here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9WZJwBunnEHjy6MMQGYSbt/7

Comment: @mickmackusa yeah... I've never been much of one for `USING`, probably because it so rarely seems to come up in the `JOIN`s that I do (which may mean I should do a better job on naming columns!)

Answer (score 1):

Still not clear what you are looking for, but I'm going from your comment *"I want to show sum of each class marks in graph with a separate line"*

Rather than muck about with UNIONs, you could just run

```
  SELECT DATE(date_column) AS `date`, SUM(marks) AS `total_marks`
    FROM TableX
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

separately for each class table and pop them in a multidimensional array as you run through each result set

```
$data[$row['date']]['classX'] = $row['total_marks'];
```

replacing X with the 1, 2, and 3 in turn

---

***Alternatively***, you may also find it easier to combine all your marks data into one table

```
CREATE TABLE `class_mark` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `class_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_column` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `marks` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Then you could just run the one query

```
SELECT DATE(date_column) AS `date`, class_id, SUM(marks) AS `total_marks`
    FROM class_mark
GROUP BY `date`, class_id
ORDER BY `date` ASC, class_id ASC
```

to get all the data you need

Comment: These choices seem like the wisest because although the first recommends 3 trips to the database, it is far, far easier to understand and maintain.  The second option suggests fixing the suboptimal database design -- which is the root problem of this mess.  A shame this answer isn't more appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your incorrect data comes from your `LEFT JOIN`s. If you have the same date 2x in `table1` and and 2x in `table2`, your join would look like this:

You start with one date in `dr`, which then becomes 2 rows once you `LEFT JOIN table1`, and then 4 rows when you `LEFT JOIN table2`, causing duplicates
[like in this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kG8m1sR8EgRR8Sfsrr8kUJ/0)

To avoid this, you could "reserve" a column for each table, and put 0s in the others like this:

```
SELECT t.dates, SUM(t.m1) AS t1marks, SUM(t.m2) AS t2marks, SUM(t.m3) AS t3marks FROM (
   SELECT DATE(date_column) AS dates, marks AS m1, 0 AS m2, 0 AS m3 FROM table1
   UNION
   SELECT DATE(date_column) AS dates, 0 AS m1, marks AS m2, 0 AS m3 FROM table2
   UNION
   SELECT DATE(date_column) AS dates, 0 AS m1, 0 AS m2, marks AS m3 FROM table3
) AS t
GROUP BY t.dates
```

Comment: with `var_dump($output)` its giving this output `string(9) "[{"data":[2,1,1],"name":"class 1"},{"data":[2,1,1],"name":"class 2"},{"data":[2,1,1],"name":"class 3"}]"`

Comment: Why aren't you posting the EXACT desired result set so that volunteers can help you?

Answer (score -2):

A mini lesson in certain aggregates:

- `COUNT(*)`  counts the number of rows.
- `COUNT(col)`  counts the number of rows with a non-`NULL` `col`
- `id` (when the `PRIMARY KEY`) can never be `NULL`. (Exception:  see `LEFT JOIN`)
- `SUM(col != 0)`  counts the number of rows where `col != 0`
- Boolean expressions return `false` or `true`
- `false` is represented by `0`; `true` is represented by `1`.  (Actually, any non-zero is treated as `true`.)
- These last bullet items explain why `SUM(col != 0)` does what it does.
- `LEFT JOIN`, when the *righthand* row is missing, generates `NULLs` for all the columns.

So, think through your `COUNTs`, `SUMs`, `LEFT JOINs`, etc, to understand why your query is 'wrong' and whether any of the other answers are 'right'.

Comment: All due respect Rick, this looks like Not An Answer.  It provides helpful facts and encourages a rethink from the OP, but I don't think it actually provides a solution.